# ffmpeg - Use filter in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the movie filter in my android project with ffmpeg. I use a fork of the guardian project : [Cheers-dev](https://github.com/Cheers-Dev/android-ffmpeg)

It use a recent version of ffmpeg (~15 days old atm). I added the option `--enable-filter=movie` to activate the filter.

I use this command line in my android project :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" -strict -2 outputvideo.mp4
```

It perfectly works with my desktop version on Debian Wheezy. But it's impossible to make it work on my Android. All other commands works.

Here the error when it fails : `No such filter: 'movie'`.

I also tested with the option `-filter_complex` with a somewhat different error:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug -i /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_export.mp4 -i /storage/sdcard0/test/watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -codec:a copy /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_watermark.mp4

ffmpeg version N-58429-gccdfa3e Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Dec 10 2013 01:12:39 with gcc 4.4.3 (GCC)
configuration: --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --prefix=/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=/opt/android/ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/opt/android/ndk-r8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -I/Android/cheers/android-ffmpeg/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt/include -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L../x264 -L/Android/cheers/android-ffmpeg/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt/lib' --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-filter=movie --enable-avresample --enable-libvorbis --disable-indevs --enable-indev=lavfi
libavutil      52. 54.100 / 52. 54.100
libavcodec     55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
libavformat    55. 21.101 / 55. 21.101
libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
libavfilter     3. 91.100 /  3. 91.100
libavresample   1.  1.  0 /  1.  1.  0
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument '/storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_export.mp4'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument '/storage/sdcard0/test/watermark.png'.
Reading option '-filter_complex' ... matched as option 'filter_complex' (create a complex filtergraph) with argument '"[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[out]"'.
Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '[out]'.
Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0:a'.
Reading option '-codec:a' ... matched as option 'codec' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '/storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_watermark.mp4' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option filter_complex (create a complex filtergraph) with argument "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[out]".
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_export.mp4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_export.mp4.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1274cd0] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1274cd0] ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1274cd0] File position before avformat_find_stream_info() is 1196725
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1274cd0] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1274cd0] File position after avformat_find_stream_info() is 30451
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_export.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf55.21.101
Duration: 00:00:00.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9972 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und), 1, 1/1200000: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 1/2400000, 9830 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 2400k tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und), 1, 1/48000: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandler
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: input file /storage/sdcard0/test/watermark.png.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /storage/sdcard0/test/watermark.png.
[AVIOContext @ 0x12870f0] Statistics: 26515 bytes read, 0 seeks
Input #1, image2, from '/storage/sdcard0/test/watermark.png':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #1:0, 1, 1/25: Video: png, rgba, 400x170, 1/25, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_watermark.mp4.
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument [out].
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 0:a.
Applying option codec:a (codec name) with argument copy.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_watermark.mp4.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x127d5f0] No such filter: '"'
Error configuring filters.
[AVIOContext @ 0x127d2b0] Statistics: 67296 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

The output is better than the previous one but I think I'm missing something.

**SOLUTION** : I removed the quote from the filter_complex argument and it worked.

Here is the working command :

```
$ ffmpeg -y -i /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_export.mp4 -i /storage/sdcard0/test/watermark.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[out] -map [out] -map 0:a -codec:a copy /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_watermark.mp4
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `movie` in this case: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -codec:a copy output.mp4`. You should always show the complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: I tested your suggestion but it still doesn't work. The error is different. I also tested on my computer and it perfectly worked.

Comment: You need to show the complete ffmpeg console output. This includes the ffmpeg configuration and version info.

Comment: Yeah sorry. It's Done.

Comment: You should format your commands and console outputs as code and not as quotes (highlight the text and press ctrl+k or command+k). What is the output of: `ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug -i /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_export.mp4 -i /storage/sdcard0/test/watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -codec:a copy -f null - 2>&1 | grep filter_complex`

Comment: Solved ! I removed the quote from the filter_complex argument and it worked =)

Comment: The output from my command will still be interesting to see if you don't mind trying it. You can provide and accept your own answer to your own question so others know that it has been resolved.

Comment: @kikuchi Using the Cheers-Dev fork, once built successfully using build.sh should there be an ffmpeg executable output? How did you use the successfully built project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To resolve my problem I removed the double quote around filter_complex argument. Here is the working command :

```
$ ffmpeg -y -i /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_export.mp4 -i /storage/sdcard0/test/watermark.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[out] -map [out] -map 0:a -codec:a copy /storage/sdcard0/test/hsgjr_watermark.mp4
```

Comment: I'm using guardian can you help me how can I use the project for filters and compression. Please I need this my project would be finished with those problems. Thanks!

Comment: Hi i have use this lib https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java but i am getting No such filter : " error initializing complex filters invalid arguments can you please

Comment: @ChintanKhetiya rebuild ffmpeg lib with the filter you use.